# how to get rid of 10,000 char limitation of SOQL query

Tags: salesforce

IS there any way where we can handle the 10,000 character limit for SOQL

Comment: Several of the things I smelled in the Salesforce API have a similar odor.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you can't.  According to this page at the bottom, it throws an error.  Being that is an API, it's up to them.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm

> SOQL statements can't exceed 10,000
>   characters. For SOQL statements that
>   exceed this maximum length, the API
>   returns a MALFORMED_QUERY exception
>   code ; no result rows are returned.

Comment: yep, you can't. Try to split the select into 2 queries? Maybe if we'd know what are you trying to achieve we can provide a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a workaround but the character limit is 100k not 10k :)
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000333028&type=1
according to the article perhaps the limit can be changed by 'Product Management'.
Otherwise, I'd suggest breaking up the queries if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i would do ....

i have 2 queres in my function first just pull ids from table X and then second use those IDS in WHERE IN clause.

Now if first query returns more than 526 IDS (10,000 / 19 = 526 -- lengths of ID is 18 + comma ) and I use them in second query then it will throw error.

What i can do is check the # IDS returned and run them in batches of 500 or so query size will be always less than 10 k.

The other problem is if you pull more than 6000 IDS then you will need to run more than 100 SOQL and that will hit another governor limit.

But if you are sure that IDS return from first SOQL is less than 6k then it will work for you.

one more option is to use inner query in such cases.